# Background color not changing on hover (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

React Component:

```
import React from "react"

const Category = () => {
    return (
        <table cellSpacing={25}>
            <tr>
                <td id="fruits">Fruits & Vegetables</td>
                <td id="pc"> Personal Care</td>
                <td id="dairy">Dairy Products</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="stap">Staples</td>
                <td id="snack">Snacks</td>
                <td id="stat">Stationery</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="bake">Bakery</td>
                <td id="home">Home Care</td>
                <td id="bev">Beverages</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    );
}

export default Category;
```

CSS

```
#fruits{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\thish\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\fruits_blur.png") ;
}
#pc{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\personal_care_blur.webp");
}
#dairy{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\dairy.PNG");
}
#stap{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\stap.PNG");
}
#snack{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\snack.PNG");
}
#stat{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\stat.PNG");
}
#bake{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\bake.PNG");
}
#home{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\home.PNG");
}
#bev{
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\bev.PNG");
} 

td:hover{
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\71AC0A.png");
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

While hovering on the , the background image should change into background color. But all the other styles work other than bg-color while hovering. I've tried both bg-color and bg-img. Does this happen because of the background image which have been already given to those cells of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` to the hover style like this:

```
td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\travel_advisor\src\image_src\71AC0A.png") !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Working Demo:

```js
const Category = () => {
  return (
    <table cellSpacing={25}>
      <tr>
        <td id="fruits">Fruits & Vegetables</td>
        <td id="pc"> Personal Care</td>
        <td id="dairy">Dairy Products</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="stap">Staples</td>
        <td id="snack">Snacks</td>
        <td id="stat">Stationery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="bake">Bakery</td>
        <td id="home">Home Care</td>
        <td id="bev">Beverages</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Category />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```css
#fruits {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#pc {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#dairy {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#stap {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#snack {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#stat {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#bake {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#home {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}
#bev {
  background-image: url("https://asia.olympus-imaging.com/content/000107507.jpg");
}

td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("https://burst.shopifycdn.com/photos/city-lights-through-rain-window.jpg?width=1200&format=pjpg&exif=1&iptc=1") !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
td:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<table cellSpacing={25}>
  <tr>
    <td id="fruits">Fruits & Vegetables</td>
    <td id="pc"> Personal Care</td>
    <td id="dairy">Dairy Products</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="stap">Staples</td>
    <td id="snack">Snacks</td>
    <td id="stat">Stationery</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="bake">Bakery</td>
    <td id="home">Home Care</td>
    <td id="bev">Beverages</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```